# How do you find a lastest pk in a Django Table?

Tags: python, sql, django

I am trying to upload new data via the loaddata function in django.  In order to not write over existing data, I need to add the new data with new incremental pk numbers.  How do I find the last pk number in a specific table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Getting last object created, simultaneous filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256190/django-getting-last-object-created-simultaneous-filters)

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? pks are allocated automatically by the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#latest

It would be:

```
obj = Foo.objects.latest('id')
```