# Want to show only the first latest post on my main page

Tags: python, html, django

i am trying to show only the first latest post the main page but still loops all. please i need help
this is the view.py:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'infos': info.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html',context)
```

index.html
i want to know how to show only the latest post when is posted from the database

```
<div class="img-border">
                <!-- {% for info in infos %} -->
                <a href="{{ infos.video.url }}" class="popup-vimeo image-play">
                  <span class="icon-wrap">
                    <span class="icon icon-play"></span>
                  </span>
                  <img src="{% static 'blog/images/img_2.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto">

            <span class="caption px-0 text-muted">Latest Sermon</span>
            <h2 class="h2 mb-0">{{ infos.title }}</h2>
            <span class="d-block mb-3"><em>by</em> {{ infos.author }}</span>  
            <p class="h5 mb-2">If ye love Me, keep My Commandments.</p>
            <p class="mb-4 word-wrap1">{{ infos.content }}</p>
            <p><a href="{{ infos.video.url }}" class="popup-vimeo text-uppercase">Watch Video <span class="icon-arrow-right small"></span></a></p>
            <!-- {% endfor %} -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

model.py

```
class info(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics')
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos")
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Getting last object created, simultaneous filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256190/django-getting-last-object-created-simultaneous-filters)

Comment: info.objects.latest('date_posted'). This will give the latest entry according to date_posted. Also you should use auto_add_now=True if you want to add current time automatically instead of default = timezone.now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply change your query:

```
def index(request):
context = {
    'info': info.objects.order_by('-date_posted').first(),
}
return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

> Note: ordering by `date_posted` was proposed by Toni Sredanović in other answer, but
>   since it's defaults to `now` it'll anyway follow the ID's ordering so
>   could be simplified to just `info.objects.last()`.

then remove `for` loop from template:

```
<!-- {% for info in infos %} -->
```

and things like this will now work:

```
{{ info.title }} # things like this will now work
```

Comment: Hey! Did you just steal from my answer? :D

Comment: I added ordering when saw there is a date field. Everything else I posted earlier then you xD. Also, since date is defaults to `timezone.now` actually ordering is not needed - it'll anyway follow the ID's order.

Comment: @ToniSredanović I updated the post so both of us should not be offended

Comment: indeed, `('date_posted').last()` could be used but for me it's seems a bit more complicated to understand (or just I used to use minus prefix on field and `fists` call)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `info.objects.all()` use `info.objects.order_by('-date_posted').first()` to get only the latest posted `info` object.

Answer (score 0):

`<!-- ... -->` is an HTML comment, if you put Django command inside, they will still be executed. Try using `{% comment %}...{% endcomment %}` instead.

Otherwise, why do you fetch all objects when you only want to display the first one?

I'd do if I were you:

```py
def index(request):
    context = {
        'infos': info.objects.filter(published__is=True).order_by('date_posted').first(),
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html',context)
```

Using this you won't need the for loop of course.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    context = {'infos': info.objects.order_by('-date_posted').first(),}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```