# What is the difference between queryset last() and latest() in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get data which inserted in the last so I used a django code

`user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).last()`

So it gives me the last user detail.

But then experimentally I used:

`user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).latest()`

Then It didn't give me a user object. Now, what is the difference between earliest(), latest, first and last()?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several differences between [**`.first()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#first)/[**`.last()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#last) and [**`.earliest(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#earliest)/[**`.latest(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#latest). The main ones are:

- `.first()` and `.last()` do *not* take field names (or *orderable* expressions) to order by, they do not have parameters, `.earliest(…)` and `.latest(…)` do;
- `.first()` and `.last()` will work with the ordering of the queryset if there is one, `.earliest(…)` and `.latest(…)` will omit any `.order_by(…)` clause that has already been used;
- if the queryset is not ordered `.first()` and `.last()` will order by the *primary key* and return the first/last item of that queryset, `.earliest(…)` and `.latest(…)` will look for the [**`get_latest_by`** model option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#ordering) if no fields are specified; and
- `.first()` and `.last()` will return `None` in case the queryset is empty; whereas `.earliest(…)` and `.latest(…)` will raise a [**`DoesNotExist`** exception <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist).

Comment: What about the actual query it generates?  Any differences?

Comment: @jmh: no, all will generate an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`, but the ordering itself will be different, and depending on which we pick, Django will raise an error if the response contains no row.