# objects.last() or objects.latest('id') ? which one is faster ?(django)

Tags: django, django-models

i need to get the most recent data of a table in django but I want the fastest way to do this.

which one is fastest?

```
foo.objects.latest("id")
foo.objects.last()
```

or should i use `get()` with one of above methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Foo` model did not specify an [**`get_latest_by`** model option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#ordering), then the two are equivalent. Indeed, as discussed in [my answer on the difference between `.last()` and `.latest()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298176/67579):

> - `.first()` and `.last()` will work with the ordering of the queryset if there is one, `.earliest(…)` and
>   `.latest(…)` will omit any
>   `.order_by(…)` clause that has already been used;
> - if the queryset is not ordered `.first()` and `.last()` will order by the *primary key* and return the first/last item of that queryset,
>   `.earliest(…)` and `.latest(…)`
>   will look for the [**`get_latest_by`** model
>   option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#ordering) if no fields are specified;

If `get_latest_by` is thus not specified, or the primary key, both queries will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Both methods are not equivalent, but in this case will produce the same query, and thus have the same impact on the database.

> or should i use `get()` with one of above methods?

**No**, `.last` and `.latest()` are *eager* methods, they will directly make the query and return a `Foo` object (or `None`), it thus does not make sense to call `.get()` since a model has no `.get()` method defined on it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but you mean any one these two go through all of objects then select the last one ?is it true that this takes time when there are a lot of data ? i wanted a code that go right at the last one

Comment: @webdeveloper: no, both make a query to the database to fetch a *single* record (see the `LIMIT 1`).